# How to execute prepared statements inside stored procedures with user vars?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I am trying to write a stored procedure to create a temporary table with variable columns created based on the linked data of 2 tables. I get the variable fields to be added to the temp table using a query in cursor and I try to add the fields to the temp table using this loop:

```
OPEN acc_data_fields;

PREPARE stmt FROM 'ALTER TABLE `test`.`tmp_123` ADD COLUMN `?` VARCHAR(255) AFTER `?`';

add_tagheads: LOOP

 FETCH acc_data_fields INTO field_tmp;

IF exit_flag = 1 THEN

    LEAVE add_tagheads;

 END IF;

 EXECUTE stmt USING @field_tmp, @add_after;

 SET @add_after = @field_tmp;
END LOOP add_tagheads;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
CLOSE acc_data_fields;
```

The Stored proc fails at EXECUTE with the error

`Sql Error 1210 Incorrect Arguments to EXECUTE`

I read through similar posts but not able to figure out what's wrong.
The DB is Mysql 5.1. Any suggestions guys?
just figured out that the acc_data_fields is for some reason empty(though whne I execute the SQL it returns 5 rows. Investigating...

Comment: Sounds crazy but it was the @ before the variables that caused the problem. I fixed it by converting all the variable names. Does anybody know what is the difference between @variable and variable in mysql procedures?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```sql
...
-- PREPARE stmt FROM 'ALTER TABLE `test`.`tmp_123` ADD COLUMN `?` VARCHAR(255) AFTER `?`';
   PREPARE stmt FROM 'ALTER TABLE `test`.`tmp_123` ADD COLUMN ? VARCHAR(255) AFTER ?';
...
```